# Central data management for custom desktop applications

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, cloud, desktop

I have a background in web programming where both the data and the code live on the server. Web hosts with mysql or the like are plentiful and cheap so using the application from multiple pcs was never a problem.

However I'm considering switching to building desktop applications but the only factor that annoys me is the syncing of data across the many pcs I use. I was thinking of perhaps setting up a light amazon ec2 instance with a postgresql on it and having my desktop applications use that.

I have a few questions:

- I'm curious as to what latency I might expect by running the database on ec2 instead of the local network, any experience or insight is appreciated.
- Are there better/more obvious/cheaper solutions?
- I've looked at the pricing and it seems to come down to 24.48$ per month for a yearly contract. Whilst not really expensive, it is not exactly cheap either. At what point does it become more interesting to run a local server?
- I'm obviously not using my applications for large parts of the day (sleep, work,...). I was wondering if I can have the amazon server go into a sort of "sleep" mode and wake up when poked. An initial delay for the first desktop application is acceptable. The reason behind this behavior would be to save money on the instance if it is only actually needed for 10% of the day.

I welcome any feedback at all on how this problem is best tackled.

Answer (score 0):

1. This could get ugly. Every single query you do will have latency associated with it. If you have a lot of queries, this can add up very fast. So keep your query count low, and try to pre-fetch and cache data when possible.
2. Not enough information to answer that question.
3. Depends on the cost of your local server. Keep in mind that you will need to pay for electricity to keep it on.
4. You can stop your instance when you are not needing it, with the exception of high utilization reservations, you wont get billed when its in stopped state. With high utilization reservations you will still pay the full cost.